# Finding a clicked item inside a DIV with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to detect which specific item inside a DIV was clicked with jquery. I have tried by giving each label a different ID and value, but it simply returns [object Object]. I'd like to be able to get the specific label or value of that label that was clicked. What am I doing wrong?

```
        $("#colorButtonGroup").click(function (e) {
            var itemClicked=$(e.target).closest('#colorButtonGroup').find('value');
            alert(itemClicked);
        });


    <div id="colorButtonGroup">
        <label class="color-buttons btn btn-cons active" id="idColorCodeWhite" value="White" style="border-radius: 50px; background-color: white;">
                <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" checked> White
        </label>
        <label class="color-buttons btn btn-cons" id="idColorCodeOrange" value="Orange" style="border-radius: 50px; background-color: orange;">
                <input type="radio" autocomplete="off"> Orange
        </label>
        <label class="color-buttons btn btn-cons" id="idColorCodeBlue" value="Blue" style="border-radius: 50px; background-color: #45b0ff">
                <input type="radio" autocomplete="off"> Blue
        </label>
        <label class="color-buttons btn btn-cons" id="idColorCodeRed" value="Red" style="border-radius: 50px; background-color: #ea2232">
                <input type="radio" autocomplete="off"> Red
        </label>
        <label class="color-buttons btn btn-cons" id="idColorCodeYellow" value="Yellow" style="border-radius: 50px; background-color: yellow">
                <input type="radio" autocomplete="off"> Yellow
        </label>
        <label class="color-buttons btn btn-cons" id="idColorCodePink" value="Pink" style="border-radius: 50px; background-color: pink">
                <input type="radio" autocomplete="off"> Pink
        </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html markup is invalid. You are giving the same Id value to more than one element, which is not valid!

You should wire up the click event on your inner elements (using a css class selector) and use the `attr` method to get the value attribute (or any attribute as needed.

Also i am not sure label is the proper container element for this. May be a span might be a better container.

This should work.

```
 <div id="colorButtonGroup">
        <span class="color-buttons btn btn-cons active"  
                    value="White" style="border-radius: 50px; background-color: white;">
                <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" checked /> White
        </span>
        <span class="color-buttons btn btn-cons" 
                   value="Orange" style="border-radius: 50px; background-color: orange;">
                <input type="radio" autocomplete="off"> Orange
        </span>

</div>
```

And the script to handle the click event

```
$(function(){      
    $(".color-buttons").click(function (e) {
            var itemClicked=$(this);
            alert(itemClicked.attr("value"));          
    });         
})
```

If you want to get access to the radio button inside the clicked span, you can use `find()` method on  `$(this)`

[Here](http://jsbin.com/qudibekohu/edit?html,js,output) is a working jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

First - you had some issues with the structure of the inputs - radio buttons need to have the same name. Then you can use the name and the value (which has changed with the radio button click) to alert the value of the radiobutton group.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("[name=color]").click(function() {
    var itemClicked=$(this).val();
            alert(itemClicked);
        });
   })
```

```css
#colorButtonGroup label{border-radius: 50px}
.white{background-color: white}
.orange{background-color: orange}
.blue{background-color: #45b0ff}
.red{background-color: #ea2232}
.yellow{background-color: yellow}
.pink{background-color: pink}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="colorButtonGroup">
        <label class="color-buttons btn btn-cons white active">
                <input type="radio" autocomplete="off"  id="idColorCodeWhite" name="color" value="White"> White
        </label>
        <label class="color-buttons btn btn-cons orange">
                <input type="radio" name="color"  id="idColorCodeOrange" value="Orange" autocomplete="off"> Orange
        </label>
        <label class="color-buttons btn btn-cons blue">
                <input type="radio" id="idColorCodeBlue" name="color" value="Blue" autocomplete="off"> Blue
        </label>
        <label class="color-buttons btn btn-cons red">
                <input type="radio" id="idColorCodeRed" name="color" value="Red" autocomplete="off"> Red
        </label>
        <label class="color-buttons btnyellow btn-cons yellow">
                <input type="radio"  id="idColorCodeYellow"  name="color"  value="Yellow" autocomplete="off"> Yellow
        </label>
        <label class="color-buttons btn btn-cons pink">
                <input type="radio" id="idColorCodePink" name="color" value="Pink" autocomplete="off"> Pink
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: I like this version better actually. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome - also would recommend not having the inline styling and do it in the css and have classes on each element to allow the class styling to take effect - good luck with it and happy coding :)

Comment: Hey - @Matt Morrow - I just edited my answer to show what I meant regarding the classes and CSS styles / classes. Essentially the class is defined in the css and applied to the radi0o button label. Much cleaner and easier to read and alter if you want to edit. - also means that you can optionally change the color by changing the class etc. Its always better to separate style and structure (and also function) when possible. Happy Coding.